# Calculating percentile use pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have one dataframe I am looping through, grabbing information from it and then using that information to find some metrics. I have something like

dataframe 1:

```
|   student 1     |   student 2    |
|   kate          |   john         |
|   david         |   kelly        |
```

dataframe 2:

```
|   student       |       A      |       B      |
|   kate          |       17     |       8      |
|   david         |       20     |       15     |
|   john          |       17     |       40     |
```

Basically I would grab the name kate and John. I would then loop through dataframe 2 and look for those two students. I then want to find the percentile where they sit for columns A and B. I have done something like:

```
perc = stats.percentileofscore(student1Info[1],data['A'] , 'rank')
```

where `student1Info[1]` holds 17 (Kate's value in column A)

but it results in the error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I would appreciate any advice. Also, can I use something similar to find the percentile of a datetime. For example, I have a bunch of submission times for each student and I want to find what percentile a student submission time sits.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function `scipy.stats.percentilieofscore` you need to use an array as the first and a score as the second argument:

```
perc = stats.percentileofscore(data['A'], data.loc['kate', 'A'])
```

> scipy.stats.percentileofscore(a, score, kind='rank')

Comment: That was it! Thanks!

Comment: I do have one more issue you may know the anser to. It appears that I have some missing values in column A, so it will not calculate. Is there a way to use dropna on column A and run the percentile without updating the original dataframe

Comment: `stats.percentileofscore(data['A'].dropna(), data.loc['kate', 'A'])`

Comment: is there an equivalent for dropping missing datetimes?

Comment: @newwebdev22 `dropna()` should work with all data types